# Grouping data in a File C++

Tags: c++, file-io, grouping

I have the following text file strucutre:

```
<Game Draw> <Ticket ID> <Ticket Numbers>*6
<Game Draw> <Ticket ID> <Ticket Numbers>*6
```

Example:

```
123 ABACD T1245 5 8 10 13 25 63
123 ABACD T1245 6 7 9 12 61 63
252 FYHGO T9736 8 9 10 11 12 13
252 GTGOH T5436 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Each Line is for a A lottery Ticket. - A Ticket can have multiple Lines - and a Draw can have multiple tickets.

I am wanting to do a filter on all of the results for a particular draw. Obviously, All of the players are not going to be in every draw - and a draw can have multiple tickets in (with multiple ticket Lines).  IS it therefore possible to group all of the tickets into multiple layers (A Map - within a Map?) so that I can easily process this information. Or Am I best off just processing this all line by line and putting it into a structure of some description.

Many thanks,

Comment: It might be helpful if you use database instead of file. However, in case of file, if I get you right; yes, you can do so std::map<key,std::map<key, val> > val ofc. can be your own type (for example Line). Anyway you should be a bit clearer (access examples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use regular expression and a user-define structure for processing as well.
This code is just a little code snippet.

```
//Originally, each data is from txt file.
//but, this is just sample.
struct Ticket_Info
{
    int     first_number;
    string  game_draw;
    string  ticket_id;
    int     ticket_numbers[MAX_TICKET_NUMBER];

} tickets[] = 
{
    {123, "ABACD", "T1245", {5, 8, 10, 13, 25, 63}}
,   {123, "ABACD", "T1245", {6, 7, 9, 12, 61, 63}}
,   {252, "FYHGO", "T9736", {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}}
,   {252, "GTGOH", "T5436", {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}}
};

std::regex match_draw_key("FYHGO");

for_each(std::begin(tickets), std::end(tickets), [&](const Ticket_Info &ticket)
{
    std::cout << ticket.ticket_id << ": " << std::regex_match(ticket.game_draw, match_draw_key) << '\n';
});
```

I hope this will help you a little.